# Socket.io emit doesn't send

Tags: javascript, socket.io, requirejs

I'm making a simple gaming plattform. it's a one-page application. The top level element is index.html, and different views are loaded into its div "app-view" using underscore and require.js. The web page communicates to the server via socket.io, which is created on the top level during the first page load. Here's my main.js and nameSelection.js:

main.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    console.log("app loaded");

    var _ = require('underscore');
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var nameSelection = require('./nameSelection');

    var socket = io();

    var changeView = function(name, callback, options, container) {
        console.log('changeView()');
        if (container === undefined) {
            console.log("container undefined");
            container = '#app-view';
        }
        if (options === undefined) {
            console.log("options undefined");
            options = {};
        }

        var path = 'text!./templates/' + name + '.ejs';
        var view = require([path], function(template) {
            view = template;
            var tpl = _.template( view );
            $(container).html( tpl (options) );
            callback();
        });

    }

    changeView('nameSelection', function() {
        nameSelection.render(socket, changeView);
    });


    socket.on('connectionSuccessful', function(data) {
            var div = document.getElementById('nameError');
            div.innerHTML = "id: " + data.id;
    });

});
```

nameSelection.js:

```
define(function (require) {

    return {
        render : function (socket, changeView) { 

            $('#setNameButton').click(function(){
                console.log("set username");
                var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
                console.log(username);
                var obj = {};
                obj.name = username;
                console.log(obj);
                socket.emit('setPlayerName', obj);

            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that the socket.emit call in the button click handler doesn't send data to the server. If I make a similar call outside the handler, it works (on page load, of course). All log messages are printed correctly. Also, sometimes the connection is lost and reconnected by itself, and after that the socket.emit call sometimes works. I'm totally confused, and would appreciate any help.

EDIT: It works correctly, when I do the following sequence:

1. add "socket.emit('setPlayerName', {name: 'username'});" outside button click handler
2. start server
3. open page in browser (at this point, confirmation is printed on client)
4. remove the added line
5. write a username in the form and click button (confirmation is printed again)

However, if I restart the server without doing steps 1-4 and perform step 5, the message is not sent to the server.

Comment: I haven't used socket.io, but in other cases where I've used websocket based communications I needed to restart the client whenever the connection was lost. Is there any automatic reconnect options? Can you catch the event where the connection is lost and restart it yourself?